# Resize iframe - do have access to external url code

Tags: iframe, resize

I have seen lots of questions about resizing iframes but all of those do not have access to the external url. In this case I do. I can insert a script into the head tag. I was trying to use this script inserted into the main page header containing the iframe (i know the opening and closing frame tags are wrong - it would not let me leave them in:

```
iframe id="frame-one" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="yoursitehereexample"        onload="FrameManager.registerFrame(this)" /iframe
```

and this the js in the header (linked FrameManager.js file)

```
var FrameManager =
{
currentFrameId : '',
currentFrameHeight : 0,
lastFrameId : '',
lastFrameHeight : 0,
resizeTimerId : null,

init : function()
{
    if (FrameManager.resizeTimerId == null)
    {
        FrameManager.resizeTimerId = window.setInterval(FrameManager.resizeFrames, 500);
    }
},

resizeFrames : function()
{
    FrameManager.retrieveFrameIdAndHeight();

    if ((FrameManager.currentFrameId != FrameManager.lastFrameId) ||
        (FrameManager.currentFrameHeight != FrameManager.lastFrameHeight))
    {
        var iframe = document.getElementById(FrameManager.currentFrameId.toString());

        if (iframe == null) return;

        iframe.style.height = FrameManager.currentFrameHeight.toString() + "px";

        FrameManager.lastFrameId = FrameManager.currentFrameId;
        FrameManager.lastFrameHeight = FrameManager.currentFrameHeight;
        window.location.hash = '';
    }
},

retrieveFrameIdAndHeight : function()
{
    if (window.location.hash.length == 0) return;

    var hashValue = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if ((hashValue == null) || (hashValue.length == 0)) return;

    var pairs = hashValue.split('&');

    if ((pairs != null) && (pairs.length > 0))
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++)
        {
            var pair = pairs[i].split('=');

            if ((pair != null) && (pair.length > 0))
            {
                if (pair[0] == 'frameId')
                {
                    if ((pair[1] != null) && (pair[1].length > 0))
                    {
                        FrameManager.currentFrameId = pair[1];
                    }
                }
                else if (pair[0] == 'height')
                {
                    var height = parseInt(pair[1]);

                    if (!isNaN(height))
                    {
                        FrameManager.currentFrameHeight = height;
                        FrameManager.currentFrameHeight += 15;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},

registerFrame : function(frame)
{
    var currentLocation = location.href;
    var hashIndex = currentLocation.indexOf('#');

    if (hashIndex > -1)
    {
        currentLocation = currentLocation.substring(0, hashIndex);
    }

    frame.contentWindow.location = frame.src + '?frameId=' + frame.id + '#' + currentLocation;
}
};

window.setTimeout(FrameManager.init, 300);
```

**Then...I put this in the framed page header ResizeFrame.js as a link:**

```
//orig frame mgr script
$.getScript("http://www.yoursitehereexamle.com/js/FrameManager.js", function(){

});


// external heights load

function publishHeight()
{
if (window.location.hash.length == 0) return;

var frameId = getFrameId();

if (frameId == '') return;

var actualHeight = getBodyHeight();
var currentHeight = getViewPortHeight();

if  (Math.abs(actualHeight - currentHeight) > 15)
{
    var hostUrl = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    hostUrl += "#";
    hostUrl += 'frameId=' + frameId;
    hostUrl += '&';
    hostUrl += 'height=' + actualHeight.toString();

    window.top.location = hostUrl;
}
}

function getFrameId()
{
var qs = parseQueryString(window.location.href);
var frameId = qs["frameId"];

var hashIndex = frameId.indexOf('#');

if (hashIndex > -1)
{
    frameId = frameId.substring(0, hashIndex);
}

return frameId;
}

function getBodyHeight()
{
var height;
var scrollHeight;
var offsetHeight;

if (document.height)
{
    height = document.height;
}
else if (document.body)
{
    if (document.body.scrollHeight)
    {
        height = scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
    if (document.body.offsetHeight)
    {
        height = offsetHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }

    if (scrollHeight && offsetHeight)
    {
        height = Math.max(scrollHeight, offsetHeight);
    }
}

return height;
}

function getViewPortHeight()
{
var height = 0;

if (window.innerHeight)
{
    height = window.innerHeight - 18;
}
else if ((document.documentElement) && (document.documentElement.clientHeight))
{
    height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
else if ((document.body) && (document.body.clientHeight))
{
    height = document.body.clientHeight;
}

return height;
}

function parseQueryString(url)
{
url = new String(url);
var queryStringValues = new Object();
var querystring = url.substring((url.indexOf('?') + 1), url.length);
var querystringSplit = querystring.split('&');

for (i = 0; i < querystringSplit.length; i++)
{
    var pair = querystringSplit[i].split('=');
    var name = pair[0];
    var value = pair[1];

    queryStringValues[name] = value;
}

return queryStringValues;
}
// window load
window.onload = function(event)
    {
        window.setInterval(publishHeight, 300);
    }
```

But no luck on getting it to work - can anyone see where I went wrong. The iframe still appears but does not scale. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to resize an iframe with an external website. You need insert a code into the parent (with iframe code) page and in the external website as well, so, this won't work with you don't have access to edit the external website.

- local (iframe) page: just insert a code snippet
- remote (external) page: you need a "body onload" and a "div" that holds all contents. And body needs to be styled to "margin:0"

Local:

```
<IFRAME STYLE="width:100%;height:1px" SRC="http://www.remote-site.com/" FRAMEBORDER="no" BORDER="0" SCROLLING="no" ID="estframe"></IFRAME>

<SCRIPT>
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
  if (e.data.substring(0,3)=='frm') document.getElementById('estframe').style.height = e.data.substring(3) + 'px';
},false);
</SCRIPT>
```

You need this "frm" prefix to avoid problems with other embeded codes like Twitter or Facebook plugins. If you have a plain page, you can remove the "if" and the "frm" prefix on both pages (script and onload).

Remote:

You need jQuery to accomplish about "real" page height. I cannot realize how to do with pure JavaScript since you'll have problem when resize the height down (higher to lower height) using body.scrollHeight or related. For some reason, it will return always the biggest height (pre-redimensioned).

```
<BODY onload="parent.postMessage('frm'+$('#master').height(),'*')" STYLE="margin:0">
<SCRIPT SRC="path-to-jquery/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<DIV ID="master">
your content
</DIV>
```

So, parent page (iframe) has a 1px default height. The script inserts a "wait for message/event" from the iframe. When a message (post message) is received and the first 3 chars are "frm" (to avoid the mentioned problem), will get the number from 4th position and set the iframe height (style), including 'px' unit.

The external site (loaded in the iframe) will "send a message" to the parent (opener) with the "frm" and the height of the main div (in this case id "master"). The "*" in postmessage means "any source".

Hope this helps. Sorry for my english.